# Is it possible to retrieve a cookie from an HTTP response in as3 without using javascript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cookies

My swf will potentially live on sites with embed codes that do not allow script access to the movie. I need to pull a cookie from response which is typically simple using javascript, but as the swf does not have access to script, **javascript is not an option**. Can I access cookies or the cookie header in the response? If that is not possible is there any access to the raw response, headers and all?

**Edit / Clarification**

- The request is coming from foo.com to bar.com
- Bar.com is setting a cookie on foo.com
- The request can be written in any way that allows for access to that cookie. It is currenlty using URLLoader.
- AllowScriptAccess is FALSE

Thank you

Comment: Your question is confusing.  What are you doing that would generate the response in the first place?  Are you just trying to grab the cookies set on the page the swf is loaded on?

Comment: If you can't understand the question there is no way you know the answer.

Comment: The reason I say that is the question is really straight forward. It's pretty well summed up in the title. The specific details of how I am making the request do not matter, I don't even mind recreating it. The important part is I am gettin an HTTP response from a server that contains a cookie. Can flash access this cookie without using javascript? if so how?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question *is* unclear. Where is the request coming from (i.e. what triggered it and is it on the same domain as your SWF)? Also, I don't know of any way to disable ExternalInterface, which would allow you to run JS -- how has it been disabled?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get HTTP cookies directly in AS - at least in a normal SWF. You can listen to the `HTTPStatusEvent` but the `requestHeaders` property of that event is only available in AIR :/ (and I'm not even sure it would include the cookie). I use JS to get the cookie(s) as needed.